# Running smsd gnokii on boot

Tags: cron, daemon

I can successfully run smsd but I could not run it on boot. I tried using rc.local and @reboot cronjob but none of the two worked. Does anyone tried to successfully run the script on boot?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to successfully run smsd on boot but cronjob however saved the day.  I just scheduled it to run every 5 minutes.  It doesn't really matter if you have the same command every 5 minutes since if the process already exist it will throw an error of:

```
smsd - version 1.4.5 from gnokii 0.6.30
LOG: debug mask is 0x1
Config read from file /home/pi/.config/gnokii/config.
Device already locked with /var/lock/LCK..00:1F:01:29:AC:C5.
Lock file error. Exiting.
GSM/FBUS init failed! (Unknown model?). Quitting.
Error: Device is locked and cannot be unlocked.
Sorry, gnokii internal structures were not correctly initialized (op == 1)
```

Where a lock file was created when smsd was executed.  Posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/paparts/61a94209578b6889442b) of the script and cron.